# Unexpected Result from Parser Test

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

In the following parser:

```
object Foo extends JavaTokenParsers { 

  def word(x: String) = s"\\b$x\\b".r

  lazy val expr  = (foo ~ (conjGuard ~> rep(conj ~ noun))) | foo

  def noun      = {println("noun"); word("noun")}
  def conj      = {println("conj"); word("and") }
  def conjGuard = {println("conjGuard"); guard(conj) | f }
  def f         = {println("failure"); (" *".r) ~ failure("bad conj!")}

  def foo = {println("foo"); word("foo")}
}
```

Why is the following example printing out `conj` as the last printout? Where's it coming from?

```
scala> Foo.parseAll(Foo.expr, "foo and noun")
foo
conjGuard
conj
conj
noun
conj
res71: Foo.ParseResult[java.io.Serializable] = [1.13] parsed: 
        (foo~List((and~noun)))
```

Also, why isn't `foo` printing out first in this example?

```
scala> Foo.parseAll(Foo.expr, "foo an3 noun")
conj
failure
foo
res72: Foo.ParseResult[java.io.Serializable] =
[1.5] failure: string matching regex `\z' expected but `a' found

foo an3 noun
    ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is [it] printing out `conj` as the last printout?

You use the `rep` combinator, which will try to parse `conj ~ noun` as many times as possible in a row. So after parsing `foo and noun`, it will try to parse `conj` again, `conj` will fail because there is no more input, and `rep` will not fail and just return a successful parse.

To try and fail to parse `conj` a second time, it *has to* ask for that `conj` parser again, hence the last `conj` in the output.

> Also, why isn't foo printing out first in this example?

You defined your parsers with `def` (instead of `val` or `lazy val`) everywhere you used `println`, thinking (correctly) that otherwise you would only get the first `println`, but you fall in the same trap with `lazy val expr`: the first `foo`, `conjGuard` and `conj` in `Foo.expr` will only be evaluated once.

Replace `lazy val` by `def` and everything gets back to normal.

---

To better understand what happens you can use the `log` parser instead of `println`:

```
object Foo2 extends JavaTokenParsers { 

  def word(x: String) = s"\\b$x\\b".r

  def expr  = (foo ~ (conjGuard ~> rep(conj ~ noun))) | foo

  def noun      = log(word("noun"))("noun")
  def conj      = log(word("and"))("conj")
  def conjGuard = log(guard(conj) | f)("conjGuard")
  def f         = log((" *".r) ~ failure("bad conj!"))("failure")

  def foo = log(word("foo"))("foo")
}
```

And for example:

```
scala> Foo2.parseAll(Foo2.expr, "foo and noun")
trying foo at scala.util.parsing.input.CharSequenceReader@764688bd
foo --> [1.4] parsed: foo
trying conjGuard at scala.util.parsing.input.CharSequenceReader@765c6526
trying conj at scala.util.parsing.input.CharSequenceReader@765c6526
conj --> [1.8] parsed: and
conjGuard --> [1.4] parsed: and
trying conj at scala.util.parsing.input.CharSequenceReader@765c6526
conj --> [1.8] parsed: and
trying noun at scala.util.parsing.input.CharSequenceReader@3a5c9b85
noun --> [1.13] parsed: noun
trying conj at scala.util.parsing.input.CharSequenceReader@222acbad
conj --> [1.13] failure: string matching regex `\band\b' expected but end of source found

foo and noun
            ^
res1: Foo2.ParseResult[java.io.Serializable] = [1.13] parsed: (foo~List((and~noun)))
```

Comment: thanks! that `log` command provides useful output. Also, when passing in `foo a3nd noun` to your `Foo2` parser, I observe (on REPL) that it's choosing the "right" failure. Is that because `Failure` favors the right-side since both left and right have parsed the same amount of  tokens? Even with the `" *".r ~ err(...)` trick, I would've expected the left side to have consumed more tokens, and thus be picked with the `bad conj!` failure message.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the following example printing out conj as the last printout? Where's it coming from?

It's trying `conj` (in `rep(conj ~ noun)`) again, since there could be another repetition which needs to be added to the list. Even if it took into account that the input has ended, this call to `conj` might return a parser which succeeds on empty input.

> Also, why isn't foo printing out first in this example?

This, however, is surprising to me as well.